# Convert a matrix of type char to type logical in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello I have a char matrix that represents a binary numbers. For example:

```
0000
1010
0111
.
.
.
1010
```

How can I convert it to a logical matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare it with character `'1'`

```
>> A=['0101';'1011']
A =
0101
1011
>> A=='1'
ans =
     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
a = {'0000'; '1010'; '0111'};
b = logical(double(cell2mat(a)) - 48);
```

gives,

```
>> b

b =

     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     1

>> class(b)

ans =

logical
```

Comment: what does the -48 stand for?

Comment: because `double` converts the char from the ascii code and in the ascii table `0` is the the number `48` in there, and `1` is the `49`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
b_bin = logical(b(:)'-'0')
```

if `b` is the name of your matrix.

Comment: Hello, it gives a one long row.. I need it to keep the matrix dimensions.